# Can't run excute the nodejs command line within php

Tags: php, node.js, mean

I have a php to call a yeoman generator (node js) line but it doesn't work for me. I am using MAC OS, please let me know if you have any ideas about it. Thanks

```
// Excute command line
$command = "/usr/local/bin/yo meanjs";
$output = shell_exec($command); 

echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
ob_flush();
flush();
sleep(10);
```

Comment: I fixed it by using this command: "/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/yo means"